# Зачем нужен .vshost.exe

Tags: .net, visual-studio

При создании любого исполняемого .net проекта студия создаёт в выходном каталоге файл /nameOfProj/.vshost.exe
Что это за файл? размер его на порядок меньше файла  /nameOfProj/.exe и при попытке его запустить ничего не происходит. Зачем он нужен?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот [блог в MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dtemp/2004/08/17/vshost-the-hosting-process/), описывающий, для чего нужен этот файл.

Краткая выжимка:

**Что это вообще?** Это специальный вспомогательный процесс, который ускоряет и облегчает отладку. Например, для старта нового приложения нужно создать `AppDomain`. А vshost-процесс запущен всё время, и просто грузит приложение в свой AppDomain — ускорение. Плюс его можно настроить для отладки в фоне, пока пользователь набивает текст программы.

Далее, вычисление выражений. Как оно происходит? Очень просто: код компилируется и выполняется. Чтобы не создавать новый процесс, пригождается vshost.

**А почему в каталоге `bin`?** Очень просто: загрузка связанных assembly, манифестов и тому подобного работает без дополнительных трюков в лишь «своём» каталоге. Если бы vshost был где-то в другом месте, зависимые модули не загрузились бы.

**А что с ним делать?** Нужен ли он на клиентской машине? Нет, не нужен, не обращайте на него внимание. Его не нужно запускать вручную.

**Я его не хочу, уберите его!** Да не вопрос, не хотите — не надо. Заходите в свойства проекта → Debug → Enable Debuggers снимите птичку с *Enable the Visual Studio hosting process*.

---

А в Visual Studio 2017 vshost [отключён](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/66). Нужная производительность достигается другими путями.

Comment: _Нужная производительность достигается другими путями._ - закономерный вопрос: какими? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Улучшением производительности отладчика, судя по всему :)

Comment: @Grundy: https://vslive.com/Blogs/News-and-Tips/2017/02/Debugging-Visual-Studio-2017-aims-to-speed-up-your-least-favorite-job.aspx: « The hosting process has been turned off and debugging has been optimized, so it is just as fast as it was with the hosting process [...]»

Answer (score 2):

> Vshost.exe представляет собой разновидность файла EXE, связанного с
>   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2008, который разработан Vshost.Exe для ОС
>   Windows. Последняя известная версия Vshost.exe: 9.0.30428.1,
>   разработана для Windows. Данный файл EXE имеет рейтинг популярности 1
>   звезд и рейтинг безопасности "Неизвестно".
>   *Ошибки EXE, например, связанные с vshost.exe, чаще всего появляются во время запуска компьютера, запуска программы или при попытке
>   использования специфических функций в вашей программе (например,
>   печать).

В общем если своими словами то этот файл отвечает за процесс отладки

[Источник](http://www.solvusoft.com/ru/files/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0/exe/windows/vshost-exe/microsoft-visual-studio-2008/vshost-exe/)

Answer (score 1):

Назначение vshost.exe (появился в VS2005) -- быстрее запускать отладку. В памяти постоянно висит этот процесс, в котором уже загружен .NET Framework, и который готов подгрузить ваше приложение в любой момент.